# Github doing unwanted changes on index.html

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

It's my first time using github and I've faced an annoying problem with it.
Me and my friend are working on a web project on github and we've worked on it for over a month without a problem. I've installed github's windows application on multiple computers and all of the sudden, they are having the exact same problem.

When I open my github application it says that there is an uncommited change on `index.html`. The change is not mine and it's not a change actually[!]; it shows that **the lines from 1 to 165 of old version has been deleted and the same lines has been added to new version!**

Now when I click **sync** button to sync my version with the latest version it says `failed to sync this branch.` [(same error here without any useful answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387640/github-windows-failed-to-sync-this-branch)

I've only one master branch. What should I do?

Comment: This is a newline problem.  Try adding a .gitattributes file in settings.

Comment: @SLaks I can see both `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` in settings

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with `git config core.autocrlf true` or `git config core.autocrlf false` setting.

Comment: Windows/Unix line endings is clearly the source of the problem, answer provides one of the ways to deal with CRLF.