# I can't finish the GitHub sharing process

Tags: android-studio, github

There's an error while trying to push a project to GitHub. The Setting of "Keep my email address private" is checked, and the "Block command line pushes that expose my email" is checked. What's the solution?

I successfully created the project 'MyActivity' on GitHub, but the initial push failed:

> remote: error: GH007: Your push would publish a private email address.

[Event log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ36L.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your logs as well?

Comment: I've post the logs screenshot.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? I'm having the same problem now

Comment: The canonical is [Winfried's answer to *Error “Your push would publish a private email address”'*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863522/error-your-push-would-publish-a-private-email-address/51097104#51097104).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an email address for Git to use. Use your GitHub-provided email. For example, `git config --global 2333223+username@users.noreply.github.com`. You can find that in your email settings page.

After setting the email in Git, delete the already-created project on Git, and start the sharing process again.