# How to set anonymized email address on github?

Tags: git, email, github

I got error when commiting:

> Your push would publish a private email address.

I see here it suggests set anonymous email address.

[Your push would publish a private email address error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863522/your-push-would-publish-a-private-email-address-error)

But I read documentation and it just shows to add in 
https://github.com/settings/emails

which requires verification. But I just set some random email noreply@yahoo.com which I do not have. But the documentation says to verify it. I do not get it. Or do I need to create some real email or use some temporary email service just for this thing so I could verify?

I do not even understand why git push started to require some email at all. Few days ago I was pushing commits and there were no such error.

**Update**

Ok, this might be because I forked a repository and made a commit. I done a commit first time on forket repository. I cannot see where my email is actually visible in that commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of the GitHub message: push declined due to email privacy restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378060/meaning-of-the-github-message-push-declined-due-to-email-privacy-restrictions)

Answer (score 5):

After reading osowskit answer (thank you osowskit) I decided to try again what I tried unsuccessfully before, and this time it worked.

I guess I have to set it like this:

```
git config --global user.email "6602631+darius-v@users.noreply.github.com"
```

The email address is from [the email settings page](https://github.com/settings/emails) :

[image: The email address is 6602631+darius-v@users.noreply.github.com]

Maybe I did something wrong that day when I created this post. I was able to push.

Comment: You may have changed the commit you were trying to push. See my comment on the other answer. (And please mark the answer as accepted.)

Comment: Lot of time passed, I do not know which asnwer now I should accept, it will be ok as it is.

Answer (score 2):

> But I just set some random email noreply@yahoo.com which I do not have. But the documentation says to verify it. I do not get it.

GitHub will anonymize your existing email address when selecting to keep your **email address private** but requires you have a valid, verified email address. Note you will need to use the GitHub provided `replyto` email in your [Git client](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git).

From the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-commit-email-addresses/)

> If you'd like to keep your personal email address private, you can use a GitHub-provided `no-reply` email address as your commit email address. To use your `noreply` email address for commits you push from the command line, use that email address when you [set your commit email address in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git). To use your `noreply` address for web-based Git operations, [set your commit email address on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github) and choose to **Keep my email address private**.

Comment: "but requires you have a valid, verified email address" - so is it not enough that primary email is valid? I have checked "Keep my email address private" for primary (actually there is not option to check which email address I want to be private, so probably all of them are private). I do not get. If I have to add one more email, then what is the point of that? Do I have to set : git config --global user.email "6602631+darius-v@users.noreply.github.com" - I found this address in description of checkbox "Keep ... private"

Comment: Yes. GitHub provides that email adrdress for you to use.

Comment: To highlight; you must use your GitHub-provided email address *for the commit*. If you've made the commit before setting the correct email address, fix the email address for the (last) commit with `git commit --amend --author "YourName <Your@email.co>"`.  (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365442/2662176 for the latest commit and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845565/2662176 for a commit which is not the most recent.)

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the following problem and as a solution to it, I did the following and it was resolved.

**if this feature "Keep my email addresses private" is on, you need to turn it off**

remote: error: GH007: Your push would publish a private email address.
remote: You can make your email public or disable this protection by visiting:

[image]